# Installing CivicRM

Tags: installation, dashboard, menu

I have installed CivicRM in Wordpress but there is no menu or dashboard. All I see is the attached. What have I done wrong?
Thanks
Paula[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below lines into civicrm.settings.php file

```
global $civicrm_paths;
$civicrm_paths['civicrm.root']['path'] = '/path-to-wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/';
$civicrm_paths['civicrm.root']['url'] = 'http://sitename.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/';
```

Comment: thanks where do I add those lines inside civicrm.settings.php file?

Comment: end of the file